# Load svg image in gnuplot

Tags: svg, import, gnuplot

Is there a way to load an svg image in gnuplot?

The workaround I currently use is to convert it to png and plot it as a binary file:

```
plot 'compass.png' binary filetype=png center=(5,1) rotate=45deg with rgbalpha
```

but this way you lose all the advantages of svg

Comment: No, you cannot use gnuplot for that. You could plot your data from gnuplot to an svg and use e.g. inkscape to assemble the two files.

Comment: That would require gnuplot to have a built in svg engine, which would probably be more complicated than adding the engines for various binary formats.  You'd have to look at the structure of the files, but svg is designed to allow one complete svg file to be enclosed in another, so it should be very possible to take the gnuplot output and combine it will the other svg in some way, depending on what your goals are.

Comment: I've created a script that will extract the paths from the SVG file, save them as bézier parametric equations, and then plot them in gnuplot. So theoretically that's possible.